# Массовая проверка кода ответа страниц

Tags: python, python-3.x

С Python стал работать совсем недавно, возникла потребность пробивки страниц на код ответа, но постоянно получаю ответ **403** от сайта ( https://www.auchan.ru/ ), который проверяю, по всей видимости нужно какие то куки или еще чего? Да и второй вопрос как скрипт после по крону запускать на серваке?

```
import requests
import sys
import os
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase


#Создаем словарь
url_link_bad = {}
header = {'User-Agent': 'Android: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html'}

#Открываем файл для записи
my_file = open("url_bad.txt", 'w')

#Открываем файл для чтения
urls =  open ('urls_2.txt','r')

#Запускаем цикл и перебор данных в файле
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header}, timeout=5)    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    #Если код ответа отличный от 200
    if  r.status_code > 200:
        status_code = r.status_code
        url_link_bad.update({url:r.status_code}) 
        my_file.write("{} {} \n".format(url , status_code))

    #Закрываем соединение
    my_file.close()

    #NТут отправить на почту
    fromaddr = "mail@yandex.ru"
    mypass = "pass"
    toaddr = "mail@mail.ru"

    sendfromaddr = "mail@yandex.ru"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Ошибки 404  / Разделы / {}".format(data)

    #msg.attach(MIMEText(file("url_bad.txt").read()))

    data = datetime.date.today() 
    body = "В файле список битых страниц за {} число".format(data)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))



    filename = "url_bad.txt"
    attachment = open("url_bad.txt", "rb")

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)




    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, mypass)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: 1) Проверяйте через `head`, а не `get` 2) Если ссылок много, то мб имеет смысл через [асинхронность](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/54a6c729101664c68e76e13ab7b52fb304cca9ae/multithreading__threading__examples/example%20multiprocessing.dummy/hello_world.py) проверить? 3) В вопросе указана ссылка на сайт, но судя по тексту, ссылки у вас ведут на разные страницы сайта и некоторые из них, похоже, ведут на закрытые. А значит, вам сначала нужно авторизоваться, а после идти на ссылкам. В общем, нужно подробности

Comment: На данный момент ссылок не много, через head тоже отдает 403  https://prnt.sc/md5x03

Comment: Я не говорил что head вам поможет, а только то, что это лучше чем get, т.к. оно не возвращает содержимое по ссылке, а только информацию о нем. А get вернет и само содержимое, и инфу

Comment: Все ссылки доступны как для пользователя так и для робота, они отдают код 200, но при сканировании я так понимаю сервак мне отдает код 403 и блокирует меня. Ссылки и должны идти на разные страницы сайта, это ведь цель самой задачи, проверка кода ответа. Зачем мне авторизовываться? Может просто как то куки прописать нужно?

Comment: Мб вам возвращается страница с предложением капчу.. А насчет кук используйте тип Session из requests -- тот сохраняет и отправляет куки между запросами: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Запустил ваш код и сайт стал отвечать 403 кодом. Предположил, что проблема в ссылках, которые вы запрашиваете. Вы считываете их из файла и каждая ссылка имеет в конце символ переноса строки. Я удалил его и теперь сайт отвечает кодом 200. Обратите внимание на метод `rstrip()`

```
r = requests.head(url.rstrip(), headers=header, timeout=5)
```

---

Поделал запросы к сайту. Отдает 200, все нормально. Попробуйте этот кусок кода. Если у вас не будет работать, то, возможно, вам блокируют доступ. Попробуйте поменять User-Agent, использовать прокси и делать перерывы между запросами с помощью `time.sleep()`.

```
import requests
import time


header = {'User-Agent': 'Android: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G920A) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome Mobile Safari (compatible; AdsBot-Google-Mobile; +http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html'}

urls = [
    'https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/igruski/novinki-i-akcii.html',
    'https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/igruski/igrusji-dlya-devochek/kukliy.html',
    'https://www.auchan.ru/',
    'https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/mebel-dlja-doma.html'
]

#Запускаем цикл и перебор данных в файле
for url in urls:
    r = requests.head(url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    print(r.status_code)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: У меня блочит и отдает 403, пробовал с разными User Agent и с разными точками входа в интернет (провайдеры разные)

Comment: Даже не знаю, что еще можно сделать. Разве что арендовать сервер и оттуда запускать. Ну и прокси если еще не пробовали.

Comment: Пробовал. Я на php норм сканирую сайт через curl нет проблем, а тут затык, все таки ощущение что с сессиями и куками нужно обращаться. Прокси подключал, тоже самое.

Comment: Есть еще одна догадка. Обновил ответ, взгляните.