# Запуск python скриптов на VPS

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

Всем привет!
Написал я скрипт, который замечательно работает под Анакондой либо просто в терминале, сейчас хочу перенести данный скрипт на VPS и оттуда кроном уже его запсукать, столкнулся с вопросам как это сделать?

Спросил у саппорта VPS ответ был таким:
Скрипт необходимо загрузить в каталог /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/cgi-bin
Необходимо, чтобы скрипт имел возможность выполнения.
Кроме того, самое важное, учесть что windows создает некорректные переносы строк, пожалуйста, используйте текстовый редактор который умеет сохранять в формате UNIX переносы строк.

Почему именно он должен запускаться в папке cgi-bin ?
Далее при запуске я вижу 500 код ответа, по логам получаю ошибку не хватает прав на открытие файла "AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of "
Вопрос что делать?

А также последний вопрос, все нужные библиотеки я также устанавливаю через терминал?

```
import requests
import time
import sys
import os
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
```

Скрипт запускается по крону для проверки доступности сайта!

Comment: «Почему именно он должен запускаться в папке cgi-bin ?» — нипочему, саппорт просто всё напутал. // «Вопрос что делать?» — очевидно, выдать права на открытие файла

Comment: @andreymal или автор напутал и под "запускать на VPS" имеет ввиду использование скрипта как web-приложения.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev тогда непонятно при чём тут крон. Сплошные загадки

Comment: Проясню ситуацию, права на файл я дал 777, скрипт у меня обходит страницы сайта и проверяет их доступность с последующей отбивкой на почту. Крон для того, чтобы постоянно запускать скрипт.

Comment: @sanitarn а 500-ю ошибку вам что отдаёт, если вы скрипт из крона запускаете? Это ведь ошибка web-сервера.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev скрипт я не запускаю на данный момент по крону, я только собираюсь запускать, перед запуском через браузер обратился и увидел ответ 500. В Логах End of script output before headers: а также AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/cgi-bin/bad_page.py' failed

Comment: @sanitarn естественно, чтобы скрипт можно было запустить "через браузер" он должен быть определённым образом написан. Что, кстати, исключит или затруднит возможность его запуска кроном.

Comment: Вопрос и был как мне запустить скрипт, чтобы он работал на VPS и как его запустить по крону? Обязательно ли запускать из cgi-bin папки скрипты на питоне?
ВОт я писал скрипт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: Для крона cgi-bin не обязателен, для браузера — обязателен. Если вы написали скрипт для крона, он не запустится в браузере; если вы написали скрипт для браузера, он не запустится в кроне. Сперва определитесь, что конкретно вам нужно — браузер или крон, и уже потом можно будет продолжать. Скрипт по вашей ссылке не будет и не должен работать через браузер.

Comment: @andreymal смотрите, прежде чем запустить скрипт по крону, я хочу протестировать его в браузере, что он рабочий и будет запускаться, а уже после буду запускать по крону. Мне же его работоспособность нужно сперва проверить. Так что первой задачей запуск из браузера!

Comment: Это совершенно разные и несовместимые задачи. Ещё раз: если вы сделаете скрипт для запуска браузера, то в кроне он работать НЕ будет.

Comment: Чтобы проверить скрипт, предназначенный для крона, запустите его через крон.

Comment: @andreymal там реально большая разница и нужно писать тонну кода, чтобы переделать для запуска по крону? Как мне понять в чем там такая большая разница? На php все довольно просто в этом плане.

Comment: Ну может и просто и не тонну, но в php всё то же самое что и в python: в выводе скрипта должны быть HTTP-заголовки, потом пустая строка потом тело ответа, в кроне необязательно; в браузерном скрипте будут доступны GET и POST данные, в то время как в кроне им неоткуда взяться и использовать их нельзя

Comment: И вообще у вас в вопросе упоминается «через терминал» — почему бы не проверить скрипт «через терминал», зачем вам браузер вообще

Comment: @andreymal в Юпитере Ноутбуке все работает, просто я хочу понять как запускать скрипты через браузер в итоге, ведь сервисы на питоне пишут и они нормально отображаются. Хорошо, можно мне помочь, как мне запустить скрипт по крону не из папки cgi-bin , думаю этого уже хватит для начала